# Specifying date in a range subsetting with one figure month (bug?)

Tags: r, xts

Take this example of `xts` range subsetting:

```
library(xts)
X <- xts(1:10, seq(as.Date("2007-01-02"),as.Date("2007-01-11"), 1))
X
           [,1]
2007-01-02    1
2007-01-03    2
...
2007-01-10    9
2007-01-11   10

X["2007-1::"]
           [,1]
2007-01-02    1
2007-01-03    2
...
2007-01-10    9
2007-01-11   10

X["2007-1-02::"]
     [,1]
```

The last command returns 0 rows.

It's a bug in `xts`? Or its a wrong range specification?

Both `X["2007-01-02::"]` and `X["2007-01-2::"]` work as `X["2007-1::"]`, but `X["2007-1-2::"]` returns 0 rows also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an incorrect range specification. `[.xts` uses `.parseISO8601` to parse these types of values for `i`, and the *Note* section of `?.parseISO8601` says,

> There is no checking done to test for a properly constructed ISO format string.
>   This must be correctly entered by the user, lest bad things may happen.

Although both `X["2007-01-2::"]` and `X["2007-1::"]` work, they are incorrectly specified according to the ISO-8601 standard. Each component of the datetime has a fixed width and should be zero-padded.